# Mirror screen from laptop to Google Glass

Tags: google-glass

Is there a way to stream video from my laptop with the USB cable to my Google Glasses? I have seen ways to mirror the view of Glass to my laptop, but I would like to reverse that and see the screen of my laptop on Glass.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to stream video from a "URL" (see https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/timeline#attaching_video ); but you would have to find a way to monitor and send a screen from a laptop.

Have you considered accessing a Hangout from your Google Glass and having the "host" share a screen on their desktop.  This might be the best non-programming way to accomplish your request.